# Folium POPUP doesn't display special Danish Characters

Tags: python, popup, data-science, folium

I am having a trouble with Popup in Folium.

It is not displaying danish Characters (Æ, Ø, and Å) which are part of spelling of districts of Copenhagen.

This is what I am getting..
[image]

I stumble across similar questions in here but no solution has worked for me

Sample of my dataset:

[image: ence].

Sample of my code below:

```
# create map of Copenhagen using latitude and longitude values
map_CPH = folium.Map(location=[ltd, lntd], zoom_start=9)

# add markers to map
for lat, lng, District, PC in zip(df_new2['Latitude'], df_new2['Longitude'], df_new2['District'], df_new2['Postal Code']):
    label = '{}, {}'.format(District, PC)
    label = folium.Popup(label, parse_html=True)
    folium.CircleMarker(
        [lat, lng],
        radius=5,
        popup=label,
        color='blue',
        fill=True,
        fill_color='#3186cc',
        fill_opacity=0.7,
        parse_html=False).add_to(map_CPH)  

map_CPH
```

Comment: Please, provide full code and data. Thanks.

Comment: @sentence `code` [link] (https://github.com/AnasR1986/Coursera_Capstone/blob/master/Copenhagen-1905.ipynb)

Comment: I have not run the whole code in your link (I have a life out of here). I have just created a pandas dataframe with the four rows in the image you posted and everything works well. So, the issue has to be somewhere else. What version of folium do you have? What about the browser?

Comment: I am using the latest version of folium (0.11) and I have safari as browser.

Comment: What happens with Mozilla Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, and indeed this seems to be an issue with the browser as mentioned by https://stackoverflow.com/users/10337630/sentence. Switching from VS code's integrated notebooks to Mozilla Firefox fixed the problem with bad formatting:

[image: VS Code]

[image: Firefox]

Comment: The "bad formatting" is an encoding issue. Your code is producing names coded in UTF-8 but your display is treating it as Windows-1252. It's not possible to say where the problem is exactly since you don't present any code.

Comment: This would be irrelevant as there is no difference in the code between the two screenshots. The code is similar to what was asked about. Only difference is in the "browser".